# Laravel artisan command testing assert exit code risky

Tags: laravel, testing, laravel-artisan

I am running a basic [artisan command test](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/console-tests) but phpunit complains that `This test did not perform any assertions`. But am asserting the exit code.

```
public function testCommandUsage()
{
   $this->artisan('cmd:test')->assertExitCode(0);
}
```

**This test did not perform any assertions**

**OK, but incomplete, skipped, or risky tests!**

Isn't **`assertExitCode`** and assertion?

Comment: What version of Laravel are you using?

Answer (score 3):

This seems to be a bug in the framework. Here's the [line that is wrong](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/master/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Testing/PendingCommand.php#L143):

```
if ($this->expectedExitCode != null)
```

This should have been `if ($this->expectedExitCode !== null)` because `0 == null` in PHP.

The workaround here would be:

```
public function testCommandUsage()
{
    $statusCode = $this->artisan('cmd:test')->run();
    $this->assertEquals(0, $statusCode);
}
```

<strike>Note: Feel free to report this using Laravel's bug tracker if it's not already reported and hopefully it will be solved soon.</strike>

Apparently a fix for this has landed in the 5.7 branch as of 3 hours ago so a fix should be released soon. Until then the workaround should work.